# How to reduce a primitive array using an arithmetic operation in a generic manner?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have this method:

```
public static long[] computeDifferenceArray(long[] array) {
    long[] diffArray = new long[array.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < diffArray.length; i++) {
        diffArray[i] = array[i + 1] - array[i];
    }

    return diffArray;
}
```

Currently, it only accepts `long[]` and returns a `long[]`. But I want to use this same method on `int[]` as well. How can I do that?

I have read that Java Generics only work on class objects.

Comment: There are class Objects for int and long, being `Integer` and `Long` but you can't really use them here, since java dopes not allow generics where the generic Type is one of two types. you either have to make sure to convert the int array to a long array before inputting it into the method or write two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert each time your int[] to long[].You can try this,

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int[] a1=new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
    Test1.computeDifferenceArray( Arrays.stream(a1).mapToLong(i -> i).toArray());
    System.out.println("56897");
}

public static Long[] computeDifferenceArray(long[] array) {
    Long[] diffArray = new Long[array.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < diffArray.length; i++) {
        diffArray[i] = array[i + 1] - array[i];
    }

    return diffArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve your requirement would be to write a generic method and inject the desired behaviour to be applied to the array's members - an implementation of the Strategy Pattern if you want. With the introduction of streams, you can do that quite elegant, please see your code rewritten in the given way in what follows:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;

// The logic context
class ArrayDifference {
    public <T> List<T> difStream(T[] input, BiFunction<T,T,T> operation) {
        List<T> output = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0; i < input.length-1; i++) {
            output.add(operation.apply(input[i], input[i+1]));
        }

        return output;
   }
}

// additional reducing functions
class Reducers {
    static float substract(float f1, float f2) {
        return f1-f2;
    }

    static double substract(double d1, double d2) {
        return d1-d2;
    }
}

public class ArrayDifferenceTest {

    ArrayDifference arraySubstracter = new ArrayDifference();

    @Test
    public void test_integer() {
        Integer[] input = new Integer[]{Integer.valueOf(1), 
Integer.valueOf(2), Integer.valueOf(3)};
        List<Integer> expectedResult = Arrays.asList(-1,-1);

        // here you can see how it is called for integer
        List<Integer> result = arraySubstracter.difStream(input, Math::subtractExact);

        assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_long() {
        Long[] input = new Long[]{Long.valueOf(1), Long.valueOf(2), Long.valueOf(3)};
        List<Long> expectedResult = Arrays.asList(-1L,-1L);;

        // here you can see how it is called for long
        List<Long> result = arraySubstracter.difStream(input, Math::subtractExact);

        assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_double() {
        Double[] input = new Double[]{Double.valueOf(1), Double.valueOf(2), Double.valueOf(3)}
        List<Double> expectedResult = Arrays.asList(-1D,-1D);

        // here you can see how it is called for double
        List<Double> result = arraySubstracter.difStream(input, Reducers::substract);

        assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
    }


    @Test
    public void test_float() {
        Float[] input = {Float.valueOf(1F), Float.valueOf(2F), Float.valueOf(3F)};
        List<Float> expectedResult = Arrays.asList(-1F, -1F);

        // here you can see how it is called for float
        List<Float> result = arraySubstracter.difStream(input, Reducers::substract);

        assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
    }
}
```

As one can see, the method is unchanged and one injects the behaviour from the outside. For testing purposes I used Math.substractExact() methods and for float and double I wrote to simple methods. In this way, the code is extensible and easy to add new data types later.

Comment: Good sugestion. Is it possible to call the `BiFunction` from within `difStream`. Or do I have to create an abstraction over `difStream` by creating another method maybe `differenceArray(int[] input)` that calls `difStream` together with the `substract` method.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you question correctly: you want to have a method like the one in your example - dif(T[] input), right? Well, there are multiple ways of approaching this: you can create some kind of factory that returns the appropriate method based on the type you have. Or you can do as you say, a method that will call this away. Of course, this can be simplified only for long or anything else. But in that case the essence of the solution will be lost.

Comment: Okkk. I get you. So the BiFunction is there for you to use depending on what type or primitive type you are using. So if you are using long, you provide a subtract for longs, if you are using int, you provide a subtract function for ints.

Comment: I adapted the solution to make a bit clearer, hopefully. The ArrayDifference class contains the method that needs to be used, the Reducers class contains the methods used for reducing for float and doubles. You can use the unit tests as examples of how you can use the code, there I made them more explicit. I hope it is clearer for you now.

Comment: Yep! Very clear. Asante. Nice knowing about the Factory design

Comment: happy to be of help, but - please be advised. It has nothing to do with the Factory Design Pattern. It is more of Strategy design pattern.